# Bigger site icon in RSS feed

Tags: bug, design, feed

We have an integration between Stack Overflow and Slack: an RSS feed of questions with specific tags. The exact RSS feed we use, is:

https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag/itextsharp+or+itext+or+itext7+or+itextpdf+or+itextg+or+xmlworker+or+htmlworker.

This allows us to monitor Stack Overflow for questions relevant to our product, in a way recommended in the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/product-support):

> Finally, *monitor the site*. Stack Overflow gets thousands of questions
>   every day and they are often answered within minutes. Be responsive:
>   monitor the tags related to your product, search for questions that
>   might not be tagged correctly and improve them, and review and improve
>   answers.

We noticed that the site icon in the RSS feed changed recently, it's a much bigger version now.

This is what it looked like until June 28 at 16:56:33.

[image: small site icon]

This is what it looks like since June 28 at 21:11:30.

[image: large site icon]

The large site icon is undesired and unexpected behavior, which I would classify as a design "bug". Because of the large icon, now less questions fit on one screen, which makes it slightly more difficult to have a good oversight of which questions are interesting to answer.

Sometimes a question contains an image, then the site icon is replaced by that image:

[image: image in feed]

This is expected and desired behavior, and should not change.

---

**TL;DR**: please restore the small site icon in the RSS feed.

Comment: Is this an SE change or a Slack change?

Comment: I cannot answer that question with absolute certainty. However, we have a similar RSS integration between Twitter and Slack, and I haven't seen any changes there, which leads me to believe that the change is a SE change.

Comment: As of July 1, 22:51:26 the site icon is back to it's original small size. Was the revert to the smaller icon due to my question?